# distutils/setuptools egg_info -b swallows leading zeros

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I have noticed an odd behaviour of setuptools/distutils (I'm not even sure which of the two this functionality belongs to):

```
$ ./setup.py egg_info -b 0613001 sdist
```

The above command generates this file:

```
dist/Foo-2.0.dev613001.tar.gz
```

Notice the missing leading `0` in the file name. This only seems to happen with pure numbers, as if Python casts the value to an `int` if and when possible.

This randomly broke part of my build scripts which generate packages based on the git revision and expect the same identifier later. The simple fix is to prefix it with a string, e.g. `r0613001`.

Setuptools version is currently 21.0.0.

Is this a bug which should be reported? If so, where to?

Comment: It's a  setuptools command. [Here's the source code](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/command/egg_info.py). However I don't see any automatic conversion to `int`, and the configuration is saved using `RawConfigParser` in the `setopt` module, and I can't see any mention of that there too.